# How to change Android default back navigation icon

Tags: android, back

When I used the following code in AndroidManifest.xml I was able to get the image 2 as shown in the image. I want to replace arrow head mark with complete arrow as shown in the image 2,

```
    <activity
        android:name="lk.gamma.pizzakraft.slidingmenu.Cart"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:parentActivityName="lk.gamma.pizzakraft.slidingmenu.ActivityHome" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="lk.gamma.pizzakraft.slidingmenu.ActivityHome" />
    </activity>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 <style name="Theme.MyFancyTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
     <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/your_icon</item>
 </style>
```

Comment: I tried this, but ddnt work

<style name="MyActionBar"  parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
<item name="android:background">@drawable/actbar_background</item>
<item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/back</item>
</style>

Comment: clean your project and try again.